# Laravel SQLite and Json

Tags: json, laravel, sqlite

I red here that [Laravel 5.3+ support JSON columns](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/new-json-column-where-and-update-syntax-in-laravel-5-3/) for where and update syntax, like that :

```
$redLovers = DB::table('users')
->where('meta->favorite_color', 'red')
->get();
```

But the documentation says it works with MySQL 5.7+, but there is no mentions about SQLite. I know that, by default, SQLite doesn't support JSON column type but there is a [JSON1 extension](https://sqlite.org/json1.html) that provide this support.

Before installing the JSON1 extension, I would like to know if somebody can confirm me that it will work with Laravel 5.3+ features to make query on JSON columns.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I can confirm that the Laravel json column support does work with sqlite.

I'm currently dealing with trying to update a server to use a newer version of sqlite and the json1 extension to support it after I confirmed with sqlite on my local dev environment and came across this question.